# Why does Android Studio run so slow?

Tags: performance, android-studio

**My computer specs:**
[image]

Android Studio is very sluggish and runs super slow
I am a newbie to Android Studio - can you help me with his problem?

Comment: You probably need to allocate more memory to it

Comment: Yes, you need to allocate more memory to it, especially if you are using the emulator. However, unfortunately you only have 6 GB Ram on your computer, I would've suggested giving about 8 GB RAM at least 6 GB minimum to run a decent emulator. However, try to give it at least 4 GB if allowed in your situation.  You should also run your task manager and check the processes & see if it is indeed Android Studio that hogs up memory/cpu. Could be firewall, etc.

Answer (score 0):

check them [1](https://android.jlelse.eu/speeding-up-gradle-builds-619c442113cb)
[2](https://android.jlelse.eu/speeding-up-gradle-builds-619c442113cb)
except these  i'm upgraded ram and i'm bought ssd

Answer (score 0):

It runs so slow due to emulator which is occupying more  ram.don't use emulator if you want to run smoothly,use it  by realdevice by usb so that you can find the errors speedly and you don't feel slow when compared with previous time taken.I untick emulator when installing it gives me some speed so once you try like this.If any help let me know

Comment: Also i am running it on a laptop can that cause a problem?? or u need a PC to run it

Comment: No problem but emulator eats more ram.So It will take more time to gradle running build.